# Line break issue with label control in Windows Forms

Tags: winforms

Say I have a label control in Winforms and I want to do some thing like:

1) One
2) Two

How do I to that? If I add a "\n" to the string it does not seem to work. Is the label control inherently single line?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the Designer select the Label.
In the Label's property sheet click the Text property item.  The property will display as a combo.
Expand the combo and enter your text, including line returns.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried in code?

http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/labelcontrolformatting.html