# I can't set the new line for my label

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble to set new line for my label. My label grid.Text only show the first character, and that's it. I already set the `autosize == false`, but it doesn't do anything. I've been checking my code for a while now, and haven't seen anything wrong with that. I even set a temp varibale to get the value returned from the `DrawMaze` function, and it appears working fine for me. However, when I assign it to label grid.Text, it doesn't get a new line. Does System.Environment.NewLine is not working for Windows 7 platform ? I'm running Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010.

**MousMaze class:**

```
  // Set up the mouseMaze grid
  public char[,] computeMaze(int width, int height)
  { 
      mouseMaze = new char[height, width];
      // set left n right wall to X
      for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
      {
          // left
          mouseMaze[i, 0] = 'X';
          // right
          mouseMaze[i, (width - 1)] = 'X';
      }

      return mouseMaze;
  }
```

**Form1.cs**

```
 // Set up the mouseMaze grid
 public string DrawMaze(int width, int height, char[,] m)
 {
      string mazeString = "";

      for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
      {
           for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
           {
               mazeString += m[i, j];
           }
           mazeString += System.Environment.NewLine;
      }
      return mazeString;
 }

  private void newMaze_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       string temp = "";
       gridWidth = int.Parse(width.Text);
       gridHeight = int.Parse(height.Text);

       game.SetWidth(gridWidth);
       game.SetHeight(gridHeight);
       maze = game.computeMaze(gridWidth, gridHeight);
       grid.Text = DrawMaze(gridWidth, gridHeight, maze);
  }
```

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407508/line-break-issue-with-label-control-in-windows-forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `DrawMaze()`, if you put a breakpoint to check the content of `mazeString` right before return, you will find that it's filled with null character, i.e. `'\0'`, like this:

```
X\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0X\r\nX\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0X\r\n...
```

That's why you can only see the first character printed in the label.

To fix this you can 1) replace the null character to space:

```
string mazeString = DrawMaze(gridWidth, gridHeight, maze);
grid.Text = mazeString.Replace('\0', ' ');
```

2) Or make sure you've filled every character in the array inside `computeMaze()`:

```
// left
mouseMaze[i, 0] = 'X';
// middle
for (int j = 1; j < width - 1; j++)
    mouseMaze[i, j] = ' ';
// right
mouseMaze[i, (width - 1)] = 'X';
```

Comment: uhm, interesting. So, even if I concatenate all the characters all together, it still have the null character between of them. Is there anyway to fix it ? or label is a no-no in this situation ?

Comment: @HoangMinh It has null character because you didn't fill every char in `computeMaze()`. So you can either 1) fill the `char[,]` so that it doesn't contains null character, or 2) replace them after you have concat the result string.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't fill in the char[,]. I just thought to put in some code for the left and right wall of the maze, and ran a test to see how it turned out. But hey, if I did fill in the char[,] in the first place, I would not know this issue ;). Anyway, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

A label is not the right control for multi-line text. You should use a [textbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. It allows auto-wrapping your text if desired you can use the `Environment.NewLine`-constant.

Comment: Would textbox be appropriate for a mouse maze ?

Comment: Fixed size of the textbox, readonly set to true, fixed width font, no problem.

Comment: I'll go with your suggestion, lets see how it works. Thanks for your help

Comment: Labels will quite happily display multiline text.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this line:

```
mazeString += "\n";
```

Instead of this one:

```
mazeString += System.Environment.NewLine;
```